# crear tablas temporales mariadb 10.1.21 desde php 5 y poder hacer un select de ellas?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

estoy intentando crear una tabla temporal desde php pero al hacer el select me dice que:  **mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in** 
el codigo es el siguiente:

```
mysqli_query($db,"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T");

$temp="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T AS 
(SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 'posicion',
nombre,
dificultad as fallos,
palabra,
fecha,
id 
FROM palabras p,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
where nombre IS NOT NULL ORDER BY dificultad, fecha DESC )";

mysqli_query($db,$temp);

$usuarios=" SELECT  * FROM T
 WHERE posicion <= 3 OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM T) ORDER BY posicion";
$res=mysqli_query($db,$usuarios);
$fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Me da la impresión que la tabla temporal se crea pero antes de que pueda mostrarla se destruye, que puede estar fallando?
El usuario tiene todos los privilegios sobre la base de datos
Gracias

Comment: Dudo que tu `CREATE TABLE` funcione bien. No indicas por ejemplo de qué tipo son las columnas... Puedes intentar capturar el error que está arrojando para saber qué es lo que pasa. Algo así: **`if ( $res=mysqli_query($db,$usuarios) ) { $fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); } else { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($db); }`**

Comment: En el create tenes que crear la tabla solamente, imagina que tu tabla se llama usuario y tiene 2 campos: nombre, apellido, entonces creas: create temporary table usuario( nombre nvarchar(20), apellido nvarchar(20) luego para insertar ahi podes hacer un insert into usuario select nombre, apellido from otra_tabla

Comment: Gracias por responder. @A.Cedano el error que me da mysql es Error: Can't reopen table: 'T' por lo que veo que una vez que termina la consulta es borrada la tabla temporal, si utilizo una mysqli_multi_query tambien me da error

Comment: Es que una tabla temporal no se puede usar más de una vez en la misma consulta, si te fijas, usas la tabla dos veces: `SELECT  * FROM T  ...` y luego, aquí de nuevo: `... OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM T)` tengo la intuición de que estás planteando mal la lógica de tu programa, ¿por qué ese sobre-uso de una tabla temporal? Además, no se ve en el código que insertes nada en ella, ¿por qué la usas para satisfacer un criterio? Además me sorprende que no te dé el error que mencionas en la pregunta, sino otro totalmente diferente. ¿Mejoraste el código del `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano justo era eso, cambié el `SELECT MAX(id) FROM T` por el valor del $ultimo que tenia guardado en php y funciono. Un Saludo

Comment: Bien. Escribiré una respuesta por si puede servir a otros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error *`mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`* ocurre cuando a esa función se pasa un valor booleano, y no un conjunto de resultados que es lo que espera. Eso quiere decir que `$res` es un valor booleano (`FALSE` muy probablemente) debido a que hubo un fallo en `mysqli_query`.

Si controlas el código, haciendo algo como esto:

```
if ( $res=mysqli_query($db,$usuarios) ) { 
    $fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); 
} else { 
   echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($db); 
}
```

Obtendrás el mensaje de error:

> `Can't reopen table: 'T'`

Efectivamente, tu consulta viola al menos una de las restricciones de las tablas temporales: no se pueden usar dos veces una tabla temporal en la misma consulta, como haces aquí:

1. `SELECT  * FROM T ...`

Y luego aquí:

2. `... OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM T) ...`

Si aún sigue fallando una vez corregido eso, verifica que tu tabla o entorno no esté violando alguna de las [otras restricciones indicadas en el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html):

> - Las tablas TEMPORALES solo son compatibles con los motores de almacenamiento `InnoDB`, `MEMORY`, `MyISAM` y `MERGE`.
> - Las tablas temporales no son compatibles con NDB Cluster.
> - La instrucción `SHOW TABLES` no lista las tablas TEMPORALES.
> - Para cambiar el nombre de las tablas TEMPORALES, `RENAME TABLE` no funciona. Use `ALTER TABLE` en su lugar:
>
>   ```
>           ALTER TABLE old_name RENAME new_name;
>   ```
> - No puede hacer referencia a una tabla TEMPORAL más de una vez en la misma consulta. Por ejemplo, lo siguiente no funciona:
>
>   ```
>           SELECT * FROM temp_table JOIN temp_table AS t2;
>   ```
> - Si una tabla TEMPORAL se crea con el mismo nombre que una tabla no TEMPORAL existente, la tabla no TEMPORAL se oculta hasta que se
>     descarta la tabla TEMPORAL, incluso si las tablas usan motores de
>     almacenamiento diferentes.
> - Hay problemas conocidos en el uso de tablas temporales con replicación. Consulte la [Sección 17.4.1.31, "Replicación y tablas
>     temporales"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-temptables.html), para obtener más información.